# In Kibana/ElasticSearch aggregate two wildcard log entries into one record

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, lucene, kibana, elastic-stack

I'd like to be able to aggregate together multiple lines out of kibanas log store into a composite line in Kibana, I'm not sure if this is possible through the lucene query syntax, but might be through the elasticsearch syntax (but I'm fairly new to that).

For example

```
2001/1/1, Info, Start "Something"  
2001/1/1, Info, Start "OtherThing" 
2001/1/1, Info, Finished "Something"
```

It would be very useful to be able to pull out the start/finish records as a single row per Identifier in this case, or grouped into a pair of rows. Is this possible?